# Can I build 2 or more dlls from C# project in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, build-process

Because I'm working on Creating RIA Framework with Silverlight & C#. So I need to use rich features of Silverlight such as dynamic loading. But I found that Visual Studio will merge all class library(same namespace or difference namespace) into one dll.

Do you have any idea to build 2 or more dlls from C# project? I just create 1 project for 1 child page. So If I have 100 child pages in my solution, I will create 100+ projects for this solution that doesn't make sense.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Just make additional projects within your solution to get different assemblies (dlls).

Comment: I think it's very compicate solution when I have 100 or more projects in 1 solution. Moreover, It need very big space for keep same share dll.

Comment: If you don't need to edit all 100+ assemblies at the same time, you can just reference some of the assemblies instead of including them as projects.

Comment: I don't get your problem, do you have multiple projects or not? If you do, you should be getting multiple DLL's already.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot produce more than one dll from a project. And its not practical to create  hundreds of projects - one for each class.

So why not just create the one dll and dynamically load that?

Comment: Because I need to load a small dll(< 100 KB per child page). Or you have idea to create small dll from big dll? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of doing is using something like 'mygeneration' or 'codesmith' which generates a new project for every file in your project - each containing just the one file/class. For doing a release build, you would need a separate solution file which includes all the tiny projects whereas for dev purposes, you can use a solution with the single project. 

Having said this, There really should not be a problem with loading just one big dll. If its loaded only once per app domain, the overhead will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

One VS project can compile one binary file. There is probably no way to workaround this.

What is your problem about having many projects in solution? This is not bad.

- you have less mess with versions
- you can work on one dll when somebody else is working on another
- you can deactivate projects you don't want to work with
- compilation is faster, because not modified projects dont need to compile again

I had one case like this in work (a lot of projects in solution). You will get used to it.