# How to create dll of each class in asp.net web application project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to .net technology, and using Visual Studio 2010.

I got source code from my fellow, and somehow his system got crashed.
With the code I created a new project named MyProj with Visual C# -> ASP.NET web application. I included all .aspx and .cs files, required references in the project. Then I converted the project to Web Application by clicking on project name in solution explorer and select option "Convert to Web Application". After this I build the code. Build was fine but it generated a single MyProj.dll file in bin folder. Whereas on the other computer it used to created a separate dll for each class.

My file structure is like
home.aspx (home.aspx.cs, home.aspx.designer.cs)
login.aspx (login.aspx.cs, login.aspx.designer.cs)

How can I build or publish it to make dll as App_Web_home.aspx.cdcab7d2 and App_Web_login.aspx.cdcab7d2? I mean build/publish separate dll for each class?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is, why would you want to do that? But in case you really need to, the only solution I can think of is creating a separate project for each class... Maybe check if you find any insights [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801252/can-i-separate-a-big-dll-into-1-dll-per-class)

Comment: I got the solution. By mistake I made a new project as Web Application (File -> New -> Project). Instead I should have created a new website (File -> New -> Website) in VS2010. Thanks for your time Michal.